# How can I use Non-linear Fitting function on Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, nonlinear-functions

I have Non-linear Fitting function like:

```
prate ~ (m1-((m1-m2)/(1+(IC50/(conc)))))
```

And a table:

```
[I] (µM)    Max polymerization rate
25.00          3.08
12.50          3.30
6.13           4.44

and IC50 = 1.87
```

I want to create a function like the one above and use this data to make a plot. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This might help you get started](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/examples/nonlinear-data-fitting.html).

You need to define your function using handles.
Say you have a variable PolymerRate you want to estimate and conc as input variable, I think in your case would be something like:

```
IC50 = 1.87;
prate = @(m,conc) (m(1)-((m(1)-m(2))/(1+(IC50/(conc)))));
m0 = [1 1];
[m,resnorm,~,exitflag,output] = lsqcurvefit(F,m0,conc,PolymerRate);
plot(conc,PolymerRate,'ro')
hold on
plot(conc,prate(m,conc))
```

Comment: hi I created something like ; tblone=[25,12.5,6.13,3.06,1.53,0.75,0 ; 3.08,3.3,4.44,4.09,4.52,5.11,6.11];   moneone=max(tblone(2,:));     mtwoone=min(tblone(2,:));    icone=1.87;   and I create a function like; function y = f(mone,mtwo,IC,conc)
y = mone - ((mone-mtwo)/(1+IC/(conc))); but now how can I use this function for each row of array ?

Comment: `conc = tblone(1,:); PolymerRate = tblone(2,:);` then run the code above (assuming you want to estimate the best m for them and you are estimating the polymerization rate)
to run the function you just need to use it like `prate(m, conc)`

Comment: Hi again, now I created a function and I want to send each element of matrix.. I used like that and it is ok: f(moneone,monetwo,icone,conc(2)). But I want to send each element of conc array like f(moneone,monetwo,icone, @(x) conc) how can I do that ?

Comment: for this issue you should probably create another question